# TCPDF - adding annotations for files causes duplicate attachments

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-4, tcpdf

We are using TCPDF for PDF generation in our website and we are having some difficulty using it for attaching files. We are putting blank annotations into the PDF which in turn link to the download (which can also be viewed as part of the PDF attachments view)

Our problem is that when we add an attachment it also adds an annotation with a link to the attachment, so in essence we are getting double attachments, whereby some of the links are direct links to download the attachments and some of links to the un-viewable annotations. If we try to remove the annotations then we show just one download link, but then on occasion some of the links will not download the file, this seems to be completely random and nonsensical..

Has anyone had a similar problem with TCPDF, we've found the source code is extremely hard to decipherer as the entire functionality is contained in on 25,000 line file..

---

**Edit to add code sample**

```
Route::get('/pdf', function() {


    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $file_path       = storage_path() . '/exports/pdf';

    if (!File::exists($file_path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($file_path, 0775, true);
    }

    $file = "http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg";

    $pdf->Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, 'attachment', array('Subtype' => 'FileAttachment',  'FS' => $file));

    $file_no = rand(0, 500);

    $file_name = "test{$file_no}.pdf";
    $file_location =  "{$file_path}/{$file_name}";

    $output_type = "F";

    $pdf->Output($file_location, $output_type);

});
```

Sample output : http://www.filedropper.com/test96
* Please download and open in Acrobat to view attachments

Comment: Good questions contain code

Comment: Hi Dragon, sorry we don't have permission to post actual code so I have written a code example which emulates what we are trying to achieve, also included a sample output
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ancient now, but it was one of the first results I found on Google when I was looking into a similar issue. So I hope this can be of help for someone else encountering a similar issue.

Based on the fact that the attachment annotation was being placed in the top left corner with no size I think what was intended here wasn't adding an annotation at all, but attaching a file and then viewing it in the attachments section of the reader.

We ran into a similar issue assuming (not knowing much about the PDF spec and seeing the same library documentation) that attachments were always added as annotations. But this is not so. And when attachments *are* added as annotations acrobat reader seems to render a line for the attachment annotation and *also* a generic attachment line. When you don't actually want an annotation this can be worked around by adding it just as an attachment.

While tcpdf only allows adding attachments as an annotation currently we've added a pull request here to allow adding attachments without annotations: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/pull/236